# Show that the following function is harmonic [Solved]

Tags: harmonic-functions

I am trying to show that the function:

$$u(x)=|x|^{(2-n)}$$

is harmonic where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$

Here is what I tried:

$\displaystyle u(x)=|x|^{(2-n)}$

$\displaystyle $$\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}}=x_{i}(2-n) |x|^{(1-n)}$, where here we are differentiating with respect to $\displaystyle x_{i}$, the $i$th value of the vector $x$.

$\displaystyle $$\frac{\partial^{2} u(x)}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}=(2-n) |x|^{(1-n)}+x_{i}^2(2-n)(1-n) |x|^{-n}$

$\Delta u=\sum_{j=1}^{n} $$\frac{\partial^{2} u(x)}{\partial x_{i}^{2}}=n(2-n) |x|^{(1-n)}+(2-n)(1-n) |x|^{2-n}$

From here, I can't see how to get this equal to zero or where I've gone wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No need to put [Solved] in the title - the fact that there is an accepted answer is clearly indicated already, and says as much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an error in your calculation of the first partial 
derivative.

The derivative of $ \lvert x\rvert = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}$ with respect to $x_i$ is

$$
   \frac {2 x_i}{2 \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}} = \frac {x_i}{\lvert x \rvert}
$$

for  $x \ne 0$, and therefore

$$
\frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}} = (2-n) \, \lvert x \rvert^{(1-n)} \, \frac {x_i}{\lvert x \rvert}
= (2-n) \, x_i \, \lvert x \rvert ^{-n} \quad .
$$

From there you should get the expected result.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this problem is "solved", and so be it; lauds to Martin R for his nice detective work leading the the discovery of Vladimir's error and the subsequent resolution.

Having said these things, I can't help but point out that this problem has an elegant solution based upon the observation that

$u(x) = \vert x \vert^{2 - n} \tag{1}$

is really a function of

$r = \vert x \vert = \sqrt{\sum_1^n x_i^2}; \tag{2}$

writing then

$u(r) = r^{2 - n} \tag{3}$

we may proceed to evaluate $\nabla^2 u(r)$ in generalized spherical coordinates on $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$.  We have, for *any* function $\Theta(r)$ of $r$ alone

$\nabla^2 \Theta(r) = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \Theta(r)); \tag{4}$

now

$\nabla \Theta(r) = \dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r} \nabla r, \tag{5}$

a standard formula for the gradient operator: $\nabla (f(g)) = (\partial f / \partial g)\nabla g$, as may be easily verified using the chain rule in the $x_i$ coordinate system;
here $g$ is a function from (an open set of) $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ and $f:\text{Range}(g) \to \Bbb R$.  Using (2) we also see that the components of $\nabla r$ satisfy

$(\nabla r)_i = r^{-1}x_i, \tag{6}$

so that

$\nabla r = r^{-1} \vec r, \tag{7}$

where

$\vec r = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n). \tag{8}$

Now (4), (5) and (7) yield

$\nabla^2 \Theta(r) = \nabla \cdot \nabla \Theta(r) = \nabla \cdot (\dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r} \nabla r) = \nabla(\dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r}) \cdot \nabla r + \dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r} \nabla \cdot \nabla r$
$= \nabla(\dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r}) \cdot \nabla r + \dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r} \nabla \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r), \tag{9}$

where we have used the well-known formula

$\nabla \cdot (g \vec X) = \nabla f \cdot \vec X + f \nabla \cdot \vec X, \tag{10}$

holding for (sufficintly differentiable) real functions $f$ and vector fields $\vec X$, more on which may be found in [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence).  Inspecting the right-hand side of (9), we see we may apply (10) again to

$\nabla \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r) = \nabla r^{-1} \cdot \vec r + r^{-1} \nabla \cdot \vec r; \tag{11}$

but by (7)

$\nabla r^{-1} \cdot \vec r = -r^{-2}\nabla r \cdot \vec r = -r^{-2} (r^{-1} \vec r) \cdot \vec r = -r^{-3}\vec r \cdot \vec r = -r^{-3}r^2 = -r^{-1}, \tag{12}$

whilst from (8)

$\nabla \cdot \vec r = \sum_1^n \dfrac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_i} = n, \tag{13}$

whence (11) becomes

$\nabla \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r) = - r^{-1} + n r^{-1} = (n - 1)r^{-1}. \tag{14}$

Now $(\partial \Theta(r) /\partial r)$ also depends only on $r$, and so we have, in a manner completely analogous to (5),

$\nabla(\dfrac{\partial \Theta(r)}{\partial r}) \cdot \nabla r = \dfrac{d^2 \Theta(r)}{dr^2} \nabla r \cdot \nabla r= \dfrac{d^2 \Theta(r)}{dr^2}(r^{-1} \vec r) \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r) = \dfrac{d^2 \Theta(r)}{dr^2}, \tag{15}$

since

$(r^{-1} \vec r) \cdot (r^{-1} \vec r) = r^{-2}r^2 = 1. \tag{16}$

Bringing these partial results together yields

$\nabla^2 \Theta(r) = \dfrac{d^2 \Theta(r)}{d^2 r} + \dfrac{n - 1}{r} \dfrac{d \Theta(r)}{dr}, \tag{17}$

and finally, setting $\Theta(r) = u(r) = r^{2 - n}$, we see that

$\Theta^\prime(r) = (2 - n) r^{1 - n}, \tag{18}$

$\Theta^{\prime \prime}(r) = (2 - n)(1 - n)r^{-n}; \tag{19}$

inserting (18), (19) into (17) we see that $\nabla^2 u(r) = 0$, as was to be shown.

***Some Final Remarks:***  I have attempted, in the preceding discussion, to work in terms of general, coordinate-independent vector identities such as (10), as opposed to executing the calculations from scratch (i.e., directly from the definitions) in a particular set of coordinates such as $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.  I personally feel this is a simpler way to do things, although the fact that my answer incorporates 19 (tagged) equations whereas Martin R manged to get by using only 2 might cause one to question my judgement in this matter.  But if *all* the steps implicit in Martin R's answer were written out explicitly, his argument might well prove to be as long as mine.  I also tried to stress spherical symmetry, working as much as possible in terms of the variable $r$ alone; indeed, (17) is really an expression for the Laplacian applied to a spherically symmetric function $\Theta(r)$, and from this the demonstration that $u(r) = r^{2 - n}$ is harmonic readily follows.  I find these techniques, coordinate invariance and the exploitation of symmetry, intriguing and wanted to present a different view of things.  ***End of Remarks.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***